# Сколько квот доступно в youtube api

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

Я паршу описание видео youtube.Как я понял, для каждого проекта дается в сутки 10000 квот и все эти квоты проекта распределяются на ключи, в зависимости сколько их сделаешь (точнее если ты используешься один ключ из 3 например, то квоты закончатся на всех сразу. Общий баланс). Можно сделать несколько проектов и у каждого взять ключ. Я все правильно понял? И вопрос на сколько это практично и как часто придётся менять ключи (их время жизни)?